# How to ignore strings where a specific pattern occurs between two strings?

Tags: regex, string, vba

I am trying to get a RegExp paternwhere I exclude a certain sub-pattern from the middle of the RegExp pattern. So for example, I would like my pattern to start with `ABC` and end with `XYZ`, and exclude any string that has `123` in between `ABC` and `XYZ`. Please note that if `123` is anywhere  in between `ABC` and `XYZ` there will be no match.

So for instance:

```
ABC45123XYZ (No-Match)    
ABCfg12XYZ (Match)    
ABC9321%$XYZ (Match)    
ABC123XYZ (No-Match)    
ABC001234XYZ(No-Match)
```

I have tried the following pattern with a negative lookahead

```
rex.Pattern = "ABC.+?(?!123).+?XYZ"
```

but that didn't work. What's the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
ABC(?:(?!123).)*XYZ
```

**Visualization:**

[image: Image from debuggex.com]

**Explanation:**

```bash
ABC         # Match literal chars 'ABC'
(?:         # Begin non-capturing group
  (?!       # Negative lookahead: if not followed by
    123     # Match Literal chars '123'
  )         # End of negative lookahead
  .         # Advance one character at a time
)*          # Repeat the group zero or more times
XYZ         # Match literal chars 'XYZ'
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/vQ8vT1/1)

Comment: Thanks Amale for the thorough explanation, I had to change your pattern to make your pattern lazy, `ABC(?:(?!123).)*?XYZ' to work on for my case

Answer (score 1):

```
         (?!ABC.*?123.*?XYZ)ABC.*?XYZ
```

Checking before eating up string.Negative lookahead
http://regex101.com/r/mD7jN1/1

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
ABC(.(?!123))+?XYZ
```

You need to put it in brackets and place a point (for every sign) in front of it... it will then try to find any sign that's not followed by 123 ;)

Comment: Thanks for answer it also works, I marked Amal's because it was posted first